# relabel clusters (column) in descending order in data table in R

Tags: r, sorting, data.table, mapping

Lets say I have a data table

```
 data = data.table(city = c("NYC", "LA", "Hawaii", "Essex"),
                   population = c(10, 9, 1, 2)
                   )
```

I apply k-means to it, and I get centroids and labels and after manipulation I get

```
data = data.table(city = c("NYC", "LA", "Hawaii", "Essex"),
              population = c(10, 9, 1, 2),
              cluster = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
              centroids = c(9.5, 1.5)
              )
```

where we have

`cluster_centroids <- c(9.5, 1.5)
cluster_labels <- c(1, 2)`

How can I re-label the label of cluster column in descending order so that desired result looks like:

```
data = data.table(city = c("NYC", "LA", "Hawaii", "Essex"),
              population = c(10, 9, 1, 2),
              cluster = c(2, 2, 1, 1),
              centroids = c(9.5, 1.5)
              )
```

I want to order them according to values in centroids.
I want the labels to go with the centroids, the higher the population, the higher the label. (Please consider this for a general case where there are `k` clusters and there is no order in the `cluster` column values. e.g. the order of original cluster column might be like `1` is the most populated city, `k` is the second populated city, etc. )

**I do not want to order the rows of the data table. I want to change the label of NYC from 1 to 2 and label of Hawaii from 2 to 1. like (1, 2) is mapped to (2, 1) so that the cities with most population are labeled with the maximum label, and least populated cities are labeled with 1**

**Number of clusters in real problem is not 2. I just wanted to keep it simple.**

Comment: I think you're looking for `setorder()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Updated] to reflect clarifications to the original post:

```
dt <- data.table(city = c("NYC", "LA", "Hawaii", "Essex"),
                 population = c(10, 9, 1, 2),
                 cluster = c(1, 1, 2, 2)
) %>% group_by(cluster) %>% #create the centroids variable
  mutate(centroid = mean(population)) %>% ungroup()

# implicitly rank the centroids, assigning increasing integers to decreasing vals
#assign the result as the cluster
dt %>% mutate("cluster" = frankv(centroid, ties.method = "dense"))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  city   population cluster centroid
  <chr>       <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>
1 NYC            10       2      9.5
2 LA              9       2      9.5
3 Hawaii          1       1      1.5
4 Essex           2       1      1.5
```

#### [Previous]

You can reverse code any variable using the formula: `max(x)+min(x) - x`

```
dt <- data.table(city = c("NYC", "LA", "Hawaii", "Essex"),
                 population = c(10, 9, 1, 2),
                 cluster = c(1, 1, 2, 2)
) 

dt %>% mutate_at("cluster", ~max(.)+1-.)

    city population cluster
1    NYC         10       2
2     LA          9       2
3 Hawaii          1       1
4  Essex          2       1
```

## or

another solution is to use `case_when` if you have more than 2 categories, and you don't want to "reverse code" them, per se:

```
dt %>% mutate("cluster" = case_when(cluster == 2 ~ 1, cluster == 1 ~ 2))

    city population cluster
1    NYC         10       2
2     LA          9       2
3 Hawaii          1       1
4  Essex          2       1
```

Comment: what is the role of `+1` in `~max(.)+1-.` ? it has to be `no_closters - 1`? if there are 4 clusters we should have `~max(.)+3-.`?

Comment: If you have 4 clusters, and you want to reverse code them, you want 4 to become 1, and so on. The maximum of the coding range is 4. 4 + 1 = 5. 5 - 4 = 1.  You want 3 to become 2, then.  4 + 1 = 5.   5 - 3 = 2. *This assumes that the minimum of the coding range is 1*. Otherwise the formula is `max(x) + min(x) - x`

Comment: In the cluster I have, where there are 4 clusters, the original clusters are not labeled in increasing fashion, it is messed up. like 1 corresponds to maximum population, 2 is minimum population, 3 and 4 are other stuff.

I want to order them according to values in `centroids`.

So, it is not as if I want 1 to be mapped to 4, perhaps 1 needs to be mapped to 3 or 2. That needs to be detecited via `centroids` automatically, not in hard-coding fashion.

Comment: This was not clear form the question, IMO, I suggest adding an edit and including a column for the `centroids` in your desired output then, to demonstrate what you are asking for.

Comment: sure. This is not the first time my simplifications makes confusion! Thanks

Comment: @No Lie no worries, that makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to order them according to values in centroids

Another way:

```
# OP's input
clusterDT = data.table(old_label = 1:2, centroid = c(9.5, 1.5))

# overwrite labels by sorting and assigning row number
clusterDT[order(centroid), new_label := .I]

# update data
data[, cluster := clusterDT[.SD, on=.(old_label = cluster), x.new_label]]

     city population cluster
1:    NYC         10       2
2:     LA          9       2
3: Hawaii          1       1
4:  Essex          2       1
```

Comment: great. Thanks for solution, and succinct way of asking!